# Boxplot: how to not show the plot?

Tags: python, boxplot, show

A very basic question:

I create a boxplot from a dictionary and just want to assign the result to a variable; for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = {'A': [34.54, 34.345, 34.761], 'B': [34.541, 34.748, 34.482]}
bp = plt.boxplot(df.values())
```

I didn't use instruction `plt.show()`, nevertheless the plot is shown by defaut, although I don't want it. Is there a special way to instruct the program not show the plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To not show the plot, use the plt.close() function.

Comment: can't be simpler... thanks.